# Is it possible to disable magit calling :git branch --remote --contains <foo> when doing an interactive re-base?

Tags: magit, performance

I'm running on fairly large repository (Gentoo's portage, 2.5G .git) and slightly slow hardware (1Ghz arm64) and interactive re-basing is very slow. It seems the main culprit is "git branch --remote --contains " so I'm wondering why it's done and if it is possible to limit it somehow?

These operations are very expensive over the whole repo, for example:

(385.025976377 #1# "branch" "--remote" "--contains" "2bb9cf91e26e")

takes over 6 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This performance regression should be fixed now. See [76998b5e0](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/76998b5e03cf6df390dba55546bbd3b3fc6eeaed).